# iso-8859-1 special characters error in query result

Tags: haskell

I use the [hsparql](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsparql) library to run a query that returns german text; and thus iso-8859-1 special characters are returned.

I wrote the result of the query to a file using `writeFile`, but the special characters are not correctly shown. (when viewing the file with emacs)

When I instead write the output of the `show` function to a file, I get the following output:

```
["B\195\188ro", ...]
```

Printing out the special character it would mean: `["Büro", ....]`

How can I write special characters correctly to a file? (e.g. "Büro" is correctly show in the file output.)

EDIT:
I know that show writes the escaped characters. Using writeFile directly doesn't work, I have to check the link given in hammer's answer to find a fix..

EDIT2:
removed, was the wrong approach.

EDIT3:
Hammers answer was right on the point. It took only 10 minutes to find the solution, but I needed to be fit and concentrated.

I looked up IO in [link](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html)

The solution was (literate haskell):

```
> writeAllLabels = do

Running my Query (not shown, accesses the RDF TrippleStore):
>             res <- (selectStr33 (unlines qAllLabels))

>             outh <- openFile "/tmp/haskell_output.txt" WriteMode

this is the important line. If I would write "utf8" her instead of "latin1", I would get the wrong result again, i.e. as before asking the question...
>             hSetEncoding outh latin1

>             hPutStrLn outh res
>             hClose outh
```

Comment: For some special chars in the range 0x80 - 0xBF, i.e. special quotes you should use **windows-1252**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `show` if you don't want things escaped. It's meant for lightweight serialization and will escape a number of special characters as well as characters outside the ASCII range. If you use `writeFile` directly, it should work with the default encoding for your current locale.

For more fine-grained control over encodings, see [the System.IO documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO.html#g:23).

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if either your database sends a UTF-8 encoded string but it is believed to be latin1 encoded, so it's getting encoded again, or the database sends UTF-8 and your locale is latin1 (or another single-byte encoding) or perhaps UCS-2/UTF-16 (if you're on Windows, it's probably the latter).

The character 'ü' is code point 252, its latin1 encoding is the byte `252 (\xFC)`, the UTF-8 encoding is the two-byte sequence `[195,188] ([\xC3,\xBC])`.

If the database sends UTF-8 and your locale is latin1, the two-byte sequence is interpreted as the two characters `Ã¼` and would show as such in emacs (if the used font has the glyphs), and as `"\195\188"` when using `show` in ghci.

If the database sends UTF-8 believed to be latin1, and that is converted to UTF-8, the two bytes would be transformed into two two-byte sequences, `[195,131] ([\xC3,\x83])` and `[194,188] ([\xC2,\xBC])`, which would in a UTF-8 locale be interpreted as the two characters `Ã¼` again.

If the database sends latin1 believed to be UTF-8, the byte sequence `[252,114] ([\xFC,\x72])` arising from "ür" would be an illegal byte sequence leading to an encoding error. I'm not aware of any error handling mechanism that would transform the offending `252` into `[195,188]`, so that's unlikely to be what's happening.

To find out what's happening, look at the file in a hex editor (or use xxd if on a unixish platform) and check your locale. The solution to your problem should be setting the handles to the correct encoding, as implied by the part of the documentation @hammar linked to.

Comment: thank you very much for your clarification. I think it will help people who come from search engines.